# Return function in Javascript and how it works?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, return-value, return, webgl

I'm trying to optimize and existing piece of WebGl JavaScript code, and the bottleneck of the code is at an if statement with `return` at the end however, the return statement doesn't seem to return anything.

```
function render() {
  if (object.loading) return; // there is no value after return
  // Loading is a boolean indicating if information is still being parsed from a file or not  
}
```

This is the first time I'm seeing code that has a return statement without a succeeding variable specified to be returned after it.

Without the `return` the program fails so its definitely important it is there.

Does JavaScript have a special situation in which `return` can be used without specifying what is being returned after it?

Comment: How did you profile your application?

Comment: You want to optimize code you don't understand written in a language you obviously don't know well? Ouch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `return` with no value after it, it returns the value `undefined`.  This is used to stop a function without returning a value.  A function will also return `undefined` if it ends without a return statement.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9UJg/1/

Answer (score 1):

It is used in this case like a get out clause, simple breaking out of the execution of the function prematurely because a required condition has not been met. Is that the entire function or is there more after the comment?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with not returning a value. In your example it just means that the function finishes executing on that line: code after the return is not executed if that conditional is true.